# Advice for heating a quadplex rental

Tags: hvac, heating, zoned-heating

Looking to see the most economical way to heat a quadplex I am in the middle of renting. My building has 1 unit on the upper floor 2 on the main and one in the basement. ~3000 sq. ft. total livable space. As per the building code here I have to have separate heating mechanisms for each unit (Controllable) and I cannot have air exchange between the units. It could be some sort of central boiler unit that is used to heat the other units or I was looking at potentially use 4 smaller Goodman 14in furnaces GMEC960403 40k btu units but could be a lot of extra ducking and flues etc... Not sure if there is a type of header ducting I could run that would keep the air separate with like an internal divider or some alternative way to run a bigger furnace / heat exchanger combo that would keep the system separate. Looking to see what would be the most economical setup or options to look into. Not sure if there is some type of ductless options that would be better or I see a lot of mini-split systems.

Comment: There is economical base cost: resistance heating like Cadet units - dirt cheap to install, very expensive to run. There is cheapest to run, most expensive (generally) to install - heat pumps (e.g., mini split). Gas can be somewhere in between, depending on whether or not you have gas in the building already. But at an average of 750 sqft per unit, mini splits probably make the most sense, and if you also need air conditioning (may not be *required* like heating is, but may be a benefit to renters and therefore higher rent possible) then you get that as a bonus.

Comment: The building is going through a complete gut and rebuild so I have the option to do whatever at this stage I just want to have something that is reasonable to maintain and not overkill. For gas I assume you mean a furnace with some type of zone system? Also with a minisplit system since its not forced air how do you ensure the air in the units don't get stale is there some way to do fresh air makeup or anything like that?

Comment: Gas would be a separate furnace for each apartment. But complete gut and rebuild really changes things.

Comment: What climate are you in? Yes if you use mini splits you will want ERV or HRV units for each unit. No huge deal, they are a good idea anyway.

Comment: Not only opinion based, but commercial property (even rentals) is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments "complete gut and rebuild". So (a) now is the time to bring up to modern specs and (b) cost of better quality HVAC will be, relatively speaking, a small piece of the total rebuild, which should make it more manageable. (That is, $10k extra on $100k big project is 10% more for the whole project, where $20k vs. $10k for just HVAC is 100% more. Even though the HVAC part is the same either way.)

If this is an extremely cold area such that (a) supplementary ("emergency") heat is needed and (b) air conditioning is not beneficial (note: many people *want* air conditioning but it isn't a *requirement* in the same way that heat is a requirement) then traditional gas furnaces may make sense - cheaper to run than resistance electric, cheaper to install (assuming gas is already in the building) than heat pumps. Physical footprint inside the building is relatively large (4 units in the basement with ducts everywhere, or a unit in each apartment with ducts everywhere, etc.).

But if it isn't *that* cold (and most places aren't, not because of global warming but because heat pump technology has improved a *lot* in the past few decades, so it can handle "cold" quite well), and particularly if you want air conditioning as well, then a mini-split for each apartment makes sense. Each unit will need an outside compressor which connects to the inside units. No ductwork (you can do it that way, but likely not worth it) - instead you use a *multi-head* unit for each apartment with a head in each room (or in each of the larger rooms, depends on layout). The inside units are big and ugly but they go high up on the wall so they don't intrude much on living space. The connections between the indoor and outdoor units are relatively small - not that much different from routing electrical and plumbing, and *much* easier than installing traditional ductwork. The up-front cost is *relatively* high, but not as bad as you might think:

- No ductwork to install
- No separate air conditioning to install (or alternatively, no complaints from renters about lack of air conditioning)
- Operating costs significantly lower than most other forms of heating

As far as make-up air, that is an issue no matter what you use. If you install modern gas furnaces, they now typically are installed so that they get combustion air from outside, no longer relying on drafty houses to provide air. If your renovation includes installing high-quality windows and doing other things to make the houses more energy-efficient then you will likely need to install an HRV (heat recovery ventilator) or ERV (energy recovery ventilator) to provide fresh air. A traditional forced air system moves air around inside the house - it moves it around *more* of the house than a mini-split does, but it doesn't (directly/intentionally) move air between the inside and outside.